# Disabling ethernet connection with command line?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

I have seen many 'disable wireless with command line' posts, but not about disabling ethernet.

Is it possible to do so (on Windows 7, 32 & 64 bit)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Windows 7, you can use

```
wmic path win32_networkadapter where NetConnectionID="Local Area Connection" call disable
wmic path win32_networkadapter where NetConnectionID="Local Area Connection" call enable
```

Even in more details ( Start elevated Command Prompt ):

**Get NIC list and index number**

```
wmic nic get name, index
```

**Enable NIC with index number (eg: 7)**

```
wmic path win32_networkadapter where index=7 call enable
```

**Disable NIC with index number (eg: 7)**

```
wmic path win32_networkadapter where index=7 call disable
```

---

Here is the command in Windows XP:

```
netsh interface set interface name="Local Area Connection" admin=disabled
```

If the network name is not "Local Area Connection", substitute with the one you're using.

Reference: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/enabledisable-network-interface-via-command-line/17a21634-c5dd-4038-bc0a-d739209f5081

Comment: Note: In Windows 8.1 (Microsoft Windows 6.3.9600), the command `wmic nic get name, index` works only in the command prompt NOT in powershell.

Comment: Note: you must be running as administrator to call enable and disable

Comment: Note: in powershell you need to pass single argument `wmic nic get 'name,index'`

Answer (score 0):

To temporarily disable it you could use this:

```
ipconfig /release local*3
```

if your connection was called "Local Area Connection 3"

Comment: This just set the IP ( release the IP ) to 0.0.0.0 ( for IPv4 )

Comment: It won't carry traffic though, right?

Comment: yes, it won't. not sure if it is a wise choice though. If the NIC is set to static IP, this command won't work.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor You could be right about a static IP.  Still, it's an alternative command if the task is just to disable the NIC temporarily in a default setup.  Your solution is far better if the task is to disable the NIC permanently.

Answer (score -5):

if you want to disable network automatically on shutdown for windows 7 64bit

use notepad type the disable command line from Raptor's answer above and save it as a .bat file

Run gpedit.msc and go to...computer configuration,windows settings,scripts,shutdown

double click on "shutdown", click on "show files", paste the .bat file in the popup folder. 
click on add to add the .bat file.

:)