# Disabling ethernet connection with command line for specific time

Tags: windows, cmd

I want to disable the network for a machine(Windows(say)) for specific time and after that the machine should be up in network again.
Could anyone suggest a command for this?

Answer (score 1):

in windows 7 you can try,

```
wmic path win32_networkadapter where NetConnectionID="Local Area Connection" call disable
wmic path win32_networkadapter where NetConnectionID="Local Area Connection" call enable
```

plus it seems like a duplicate question...

[Disabling ethernet connection with command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19021466/disabling-ethernet-connection-with-command-line)

you could have got help from super-user stack exchange,

https://superuser.com/questions/520755/bat-file-to-disable-ethernet-adaptor-and-then-reenable-it-after-windows-log-in

the answer that seemed more suited, still .bat file approach is better,

```
@echo on
timeout /t 10
netsh interface set interface "Local Area Connection" DISABLED
timeout /t 10
netsh interface set interface "Local Area Connection" ENABLED
```

Comment: Yes i already looked into this suggestion but I want to disconnect the network lets say for 30 seconds.

Comment: Lets say there are 2 machines A and B:
From machine A, I want to fire some command remotely so that the network on Machine B is disconnected for specific time and it should again reconnnect after 30 seconds or so.
Assuming here both are windows machine.

Comment: you can take a telnet connection to machine A and fire the disabling command... if you write a batch file specifying the commands in it, i.e. disable (for a duration) then sleep (few secs) then enable (after sleep duration) i guess your purpose will be served better.

Comment: you can also schedule jobs with AT. See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726974.aspx

Comment: You want to disable and enable ethernet of only one machine right ??? remotely from the second machine ??? if my understanding is correct then what can be the problem ??? you take telnet connection of A from B and write the .bat file and execute it on the machine A. Machine A will then keep disabling and enabling the ethernet.

Comment: thanks Amarjit but main problem I was facing is there are 2 machines A and B as i said:
Am firing command remotely from A to Machine B.
I already saw this suggestion in super user but it will not work in my scenario because:
@echo on
timeout /t 10
netsh interface set interface "Local Area Connection" DISABLED -- After this the remote machine B is no more reachable to A, so the following command to be fired from machine B as it is disconnected from the network now.
timeout /t 10
netsh interface set interface "Local Area Connection" ENABLED

Comment: scenario needed:
I have to fire some command from A --> B so that B's network would be disabled for lets say 30 seconds, I mean is there any option to mention the time interval to disconnect a machine's network remotely for sometime.

Comment: one bypass is, open telnet connection, create a .bat file, in the .bat file put the instructions of disabling and enabling and fire the .bat file. Once executed, the .bat file will by itself disable the interface and after the specified time it will enable by itself. you do not need to worry about it.

Comment: the time can be mentioned in timeout /t (secs) such as timeout /t 10 for 10 secs. timeout /t 30 for 30 secs

Comment: Thanks Amarjit, would be trying your suggestion.

Comment: you did not tell if the suggestion worked or not, if it was helpful then close the question.